# hbase delete region from hbase:meta

Tags: hbase, region

I want to delete region from hbase table. 
I am using cloudera version 6.1.1 and hbase version 2.1.0

I performed the following steps to delete.

- Disable table from hbase shell
- Delete region from hbase:meta table
- Delete data from hdfs
- Enable table from hbase shell

But after enabling hbase table, deleted region came back again. 
Am I missing something? Or Is there any better way to delete whole region from hbase table?

Comment: Have you tried merging new (empty?) region with its neighbor after your table is back online? https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_online_region_merges

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried merging empty region with its neighbour. But the problem is I have around 2k region to be deleted. So merging would be tedious. But it seems there is no other way.

Comment: In that case, you can enable table normalizer, and let HBase itself merge empty regions. https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#normalizer